# List of subclass objects reinterpreted as a list of base class objects? (C++11)

Tags: c++, list, inheritance, type-conversion

I've been working with a library that provides polygonal triangulation. Since I'm trying to tack on some more information (an ID and a bunch of methods) to the polygons it consumes and the triangles it returns, I inherited its internal polygon class (Poly) to create my own polygon class (PolyMine). I have a list of hundreds of those Polygons, enough of them that iterating them for any conversion takes quite a while. I cannot allocate memory beforehand as I'm consuming an unknown number of polygons from an SVG file at runtime.

Here's the definition:

```
class PolyMine : public Poly
{
public:
  void AddPoint(float _x, float _y);

private:
  int id
  // ...etc
}
```

I'm creating a list of objects:

```
std::list<PolyMine> outlinePolygons;
std::list<PolyMine> resultTriangles;
```

and wanted to use them in the triangulation:

```
Triangulate(&outlinePolygons, &resultTriangles);
```

but, as people with more experience in C++ might already see, this isn't working as `Triangulate` expects a pointer to a `Poly` list. Now, I was under the impression that in this case, the program would simply 'skip' the parts of `PolyMine` that are not in `Poly` and use the list as such.

After attempting to google the issue, I haven't come up with anything except C# solutions. At this point, I'm assuming I lack the verbage to actually formulate a good search query.

Do I really have to iterate over the list just to recast the children to their parent type? Is there a conversion I am missing? Is this not even possible or plausible? Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: "I was under the impression that in this case, the program would simply 'skip' the parts of PolyMine that are not in Poly" You were mistaken.  A `list<Poly>` and `list<PolyMine>` are 100% unrelated, and the compiler knows it.

Comment: @MooingDuck My confusion stems from the simplicity of being able to do this: `Poly a = b;` where b is a 'PolyMine'. It's just 'downgraded', if you will. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work or not, but you could try passing in a list of pointers to Triangulate. That way you can have PolyMine objects stored in it. Might be worth getting a little more familiar with polymorphism.

`std::list<Poly *> outlinePolygons; // Still fill it with PolyMine objects`

Then you could try passing that in. Again not sure if it'll work but worth a shot

Comment: @picklechips Triangulate is a library function I cannot edit. If there is no "convenient" solution, I will likely have to just iterate and convert each item. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I understand, and you shouldn't have to edit it. Santiago Varela just posted an answer with what I was saying, take a look there.

Comment: Triangulate(const std::list<Poly*>& l1, std::list<Poly*> & l1); is this the function signature? Or Triangulate(const std::list<Poly*>*& l1, std::list<Poly*>* & l1);?
Mind sharing the signature for Triangulate, so we can finish helping you with your problem.

Comment: @SantiagoVarela Thank you kindly for all the work you've done already. The signature is `Triangulate(std::list<Poly> *inpolys, std::list<Poly> *outtris);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ you use pointers and dynamic memory for Generalisation/Inheritance.

You can make your lists to Poly pointers:

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<Poly>> outlinePolygons;
std::list<std::unique_ptr<Poly>> resultTriangles;

Poly* childPoly = new PolyMine;
Poly* childPoly2 = new AnotherPoly;  // Another derived class from Poly
outlinePolygons.insert(childPoly);
outlinePolygons.insert(childPoly2);
```

In this way you're storing all `Poly` references to your concrete derived objects.

### Update

Knowing that the `Triangulate` function signature is:

```
Triangulate(std::list<Poly> *inpolys, std::list<Poly> *outtris);
```

Your lists can now be instantiated with smart pointers like so:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::list<Poly>> outlinePolygons = new std::list<Poly>;
std::unique_ptr<std::list<Poly>> resultTriangles = new std::list<Poly>;
```

`Triangulate` will now work, but I foresee that there will be a problem, because `std::list<Poly*>` or `std::list<std:unique_ptr<<Poly>>` is different from `std::list<Poly>*`, which is what `Triangulate` expects as its two arguments. You will not be able to populate list `std::list<Poly>*` with `PolyMine` derived class objects, unless you can create another function which takes `Poly*` lists:

```
Triangulate(std::list<Poly*> *inpolys, std::list<Poly*> *outtris); // A function with the same name but different parameter types is allowed in C++.
```

Comment: You'll also have to remember to delete the objects when you're done with them when doing it this way.

Comment: Thanks. @GuillaumeRacicot has now used std::unique_ptr (smart pointer) which takes away the pain of having to deallocate (delete) memory.